# Invalid from phone number in Twilio SMS gateway

Tags: php, twilio-api

[image: Screenshot]

I am using Twilio SMS gateway. I am using india country code +91 with my indian phone number. I am getting an error as shown in the screenshot.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
$account_sid = '#######################';
$auth_token = '#######################';
$twilio_number = '+91**********';
$client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);
$client->messages->create(
// Where to send a text message (your cell phone?)
'+91**********',
array(
    'from' => $twilio_number,
    'body' => 'I sent this message in under 10 minutes!'
)
);

?>
```

Can anyone help, why I am receiving this error?

Comment: Which part of the error message is not clear to you? The provided number cannot be used to delivery SMS to it.

Comment: It gives me invalid from phone number. I am using indian phone number with india's country code +91. I can't display private phone number, so i have kept * instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, we have to buy number after login:

So, already bought numbers displayed here: https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming

and if we want to buy new one, we can buy it from here: https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming

So, the thing is we have to put from number which we have bought from account. For me it worked like this.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is still in trial mode, you need to add your destination phone number to verified caller ids in your twillio account dashboard

> https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/verified

Comment: thank you, the number was verified still it was not working